# GCP Pub/Sub Push Endpoint cannot find google domain verification token in request parameters

Tags: python, google-cloud-pubsub

I have set up a push endpoint on Google's Pub/Sub platform and when I am reading the docs I see this snippet of code:

```
def receive_messages_handler():
    # Verify that the request originates from the application.
    if (request.args.get('token', '') !=
            current_app.config['PUBSUB_VERIFICATION_TOKEN']):
        return 'Invalid request', 400
```

but whenever I look into the request args/parameters of the POST request on the push endpoint, I never find any token attribute in the query parameters. I have enabled the Roles/iam.TokenCreator role in the admin in order to create tokens and such. Am I still missing something? Or has Google removed this token from their parameters?

This `token` parameter is meant to verify the origination of the request.

Comment: What is the URL/link to the docs that you mention?

Comment: Did you check in the request header?

Comment: Ive looked in the request header, and it gives the Bearer Auth token, but from that code snippet the bearer token is different from the one I mentioned in the post

Answer (score 0):

The `PUBSUB_VERIFICATION_TOKEN` is set by the application, its value is in [`app.yaml`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard_python37/pubsub/app.yaml#L5-L8). If someone tries to listen to the Cloud Pub/Sub push endpoint (for example, `"https://<your-project-id>.appspot.com/push-handlers/receive_messages?token=1234abc"`) with a verification token other than what you have specified in the `yaml` file, they will not succeed in getting anything.

With a push subscription, Cloud Pub/Sub also includes a token (JWT) with each push request. The `serviceAccountTokenCreator` role is to allow Cloud Pub/Sub to generate tokens. This is to make sure that on the application side, if the application chooses to, it can do things like verifying if the data is indeed coming from Cloud Pub/Sub.